Identical particles and the fundamental group of classical configuration space
I have read through Leinaas and Myrheim's paper. I will first present my understanding, then ask my questions.
My Understanding
We consider some classical configuration space$^1$ $X$. Let $h$ be a Hilbert space describing the internal space of the to-be quantum system. We construct a vector bundle $(X, h, E, \pi)$ where $E$ is the total space and $\pi: E \to X$ is the projection. We define a quantum state as a section $\Psi: X \to E$ of the vector bundle. Hence, locally (upon taking a projection) $\Psi_{x_0}: U_{x_0} \to h$, which is close enough to the usual notion of a quantum state.
In order to take derivatives of sections of a vector bundle, we introduce a connection via a (not necessarily unique) connection $1$-form $b$. We define the corresponding parallel transport operator via
$$P(x + dx, x) := 1 + idx^kb_k(x)$$
which induces the covariant derivative
$$D_k := \partial_k + ib_k(x)$$
which induces the curvature
$$F_{kl} := [D_k, D_l].$$
Here is where we start to make many assumptions.

We constrain the connection to be flat $F_{kl} = 0$. Flat connections are classified by representations $P: \pi_1(X) \to GL(h)$.
We impose the constraint that a valid connection $b$ must correspond to a unitary representation $P: \pi_1(X) \to U(\dim h)$.
Typically, for an $N$ particle quantum system we have $h = \otimes_{i=1}^N h^{(i)}$. This space is endowed with an appropriate irreducible representation $\iota: \oplus_{i=1}^N \mathfrak{su}(2)^{(i)} \to \mathfrak{gl}(h)$.
We impose the further constraint on $P$ that for each $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(X)$ the parallel transport operator $P_{[\gamma]}: h \to h$ acts one of two ways:
$$P_{[\gamma]}\iota(o)P_{[\gamma]}^{-1} = \iota(o) $$
or
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    &P_{[\gamma]}\iota(o)P_{[\gamma]}^{-1} = R_\pi \iota(o) R_\pi^{-1} \\
    &\iff R_\pi^{-1} P_{[\gamma]}\iota(o)P_{[\gamma]}^{-1}R_\pi =  \iota(o) 
    \end{aligned}
$$
where $R: S_N \to U(\dim h)$ is a unitary representation of the symmetric group, $\pi \in S_N$, and $o \in \oplus_{i=1}^N \mathfrak{su}(2)^{(i)}$. By Shur's lemma and unitarity the first case implies
$$
    P_{[\gamma]} = e^{i\xi([\gamma])} \mathbb{I}
$$
and the second case implies
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &R_\pi^{-1} P_{[\gamma]} = e^{i\xi([\gamma])} \mathbb{I} \\
    &\iff P_{[\gamma]} = e^{i\xi([\gamma])} R_\pi
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\xi: \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ characterizes the particle statistics of the system.

Questions

The paper restricts $R_\pi$ to not be an arbitrary element of the image of a representation $\pi: S_N \to U(\dim h)$, but rather to only be a "transposition operator" which acts like $T(\Psi_1 \otimes \Psi_2) = \Psi_2 \otimes \Psi_1$. Can we weaken this restriction to allow arbitrary elements of the image of a representation of the symmetric group as I have written?
Why do people say that particle statistics comes from (qualitative statement) representations of the fundamental group of configuration space? Seemingly, the situation is more complicated because we ignore certain representations of the fundamental group of configuration space via the assumptions bulleted above.



Configuration space in the sense of classical mechanics.


The last part of the paper explains that there is no loss of generality in considering flat connection. When it is actually not flat, i.e. there is a nonzero force field, you can just treat the force field normally, and then redo all the arguments on top of the force field, treating it as if it were a background. The arguments then follow through mutatis mutandis and the same results are obtained.
